# DJANGO-TEMPLATES: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'child'

Tags: django

Al crear un directorio templates e indicar en el setting la hubicación, me devuelve un error que no consigo solventar.

Code:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.child('templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de reemplazar la sentencia de error (la key 'DIRS') por:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Quedará así:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

O podrías utilizar la librería Path:

```
from unipath import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (BASE_DIR.child('templates'),),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Devuelve el mismo error:  'DIRS': (BASE_DIR.child('templates'),),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'child'

Comment: Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: En la documentación aparece como: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],. Lo has probado así? Lo edito. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/

Comment: Almenos el error es diferente: TemplateDoesNotExist at /

inicio.html

Comment: Has probado la segunda opción que te he propuesto? La de utilizar la librería Path de python.

Comment: Sí con la segunda opción no sale el AttributeError 'str", ya sale TemplateDoesNotExist. Supongo que esto ya es otro tema ta. Gracias.